# Network configuration to route trafic between different services for KVM hosts and VMs

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization

We've got 3 KVM hosts (CentOS 7) with several Virtual Machines running on them, each serving different services like FTP, HTTP, SSH, etc. We've got just one external (dynamic) IP with a noip.com domain.
I need to find a way, (like a reverse proxy for HTTP Servers) to route the different requests for different services to the corresponding VM IP/port.
What do I need to configure/install in order to achieve this routing?
Thank you for your help.

Edit: I'm adding a diagram that I hope it can explain better what I want to achieve.

[image: datacenter diagram]

Comment: I added a diagram to explain what I need. In this example, I would like to reach the virtual servers by it domain name, i.e. with the command ssh user@vm2.example.com to reach port 22 of VM2 hosted on Host 1, http://vm6.example.com to reach port 80 of VM6 hosted on Host 2, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place the VMs behing a libvirt NAT network, you can forward the ports accordingly, so specific traffic coming in to the physical machine's IP will be directed to a port on a VM.

The official documentation recommends a libvirt hook to be used, the code it pretty simple: https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Networking#Forwarding_Incoming_Connections

EDIT: Otherwise, with a single IP your best bet is to set up VPN

Comment: But I can't use port redirection because I have the same services in different VMs on different KVM hosts. E.g. ftp servers that use the same ports, etc.

Comment: see edit in the answer

Answer (score 1):

SSH doesn't support "virtual hosts".

Some FTP deamons support Virtual Hosts, but unfortunately not all clients are following RFC 7151.

HTTP supports a Virtual Hosts, so you just need a reverse proxy on your primary IP (ie: nginx, apache's mod_proxy etc.)

As to what solutions you could use, other than the mentioned one above (VPN), you could just use different external ports.

So, if you have VM1, VM2, and VM3, you could redirect ports 2201, 2202, 2203 to the internal port 22 on VM1, VM2, VM3 so on.

You could also do the same for FTP (2101 -> VM1:21, 2102 -> VM2:21 etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Znuff. But if I use different domains instead of subdomains? Can I forward the services to the standard ports of each virtual machine? I.e. ssh user@domain1.com to VM1, ssh user@domain2.com to VM2, etc.?

Comment: No, you can not do that. SSH doesn't care about the hostname. Like I said  - it doesn't support virtual hosts.